# Clear function not clearing selected ranges

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have a sheet called "Print" that I want to copy data to from a sheet called "DatabaseIF". I am trying to clear the entire range on the "print" sheet before a new entry is loaded into that sheet but I run into the (Runtime Error '1004' "Application-defined or Object-defined error” when Selecting Range). As of now it does not clear any of the range of cells I have selected and just copies the value from "DatabaseIF" to the next available row. My code is as follows:

```
Private Sub cmbReport_Click()

Dim iValIF As Integer
Dim iValCA As Integer
Dim iValCB As Integer
    
  Sheets("DatabaseIF").AutoFilterMode = False

iValIF = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SDes").range("Dyn_DBif1"), Me.cbBID.Value)

iValCA = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database").range("Dyn_DBca1"), Me.cbBID.Value)

iValCB = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DatabaseCB").range("Dyn_DBcb1"), Me.cbBID.Value)

    If iValIF <> iValCA Then
        MsgBox "There are missing cylinder analysis values for this batch number. An engineering report can not be created.", vbCritical, "Missing Cylinder Analysis Values"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If iValIF <> iValCB Then
        MsgBox "There are missing cylinder breaking values for this batch number. An engineering report can not be created.", vbCritical, "Missing Cylinder Breaking Values"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    
    Sheets("Print").range("A2:AK100").clear 'THIS IS THE CODE THAT GIVES THE RUNTIME ERROR
    
    Sheets("DatabaseIF").range("Dyn_DBIF").AutoFilter 1, CR_UF.cbBID
    Sheets("DatabaseIF").range("Dyn_DBIF").Copy Sheets("Print").range("A2")

    Sheets("DatabaseIF").AutoFilterMode = False


End Sub
```

Comment: Fully qualify the reference. Starting with the workbook. When you call `Sheets` it defaults to `ActiveWorkbook`. If the wrong workbook is active then you get an error.

Comment: Typo on your sheet name "Print" ? Maybe there a space behind it